# C++ - Copying an Hash-table to another Hash-table

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to "re-size" an Hash-table by copying the elements of the current Hash-table to another Hash-table, change the size of the first Hash-table and copying the the elements back. By the way, when copying form the first to the second, the location of the elements are re-calculated using the size of the second Hash-table.

My problem is that the second hash-table is not even printing the second hash-table.

Here is my code:

```
void intHashTable::rehash(int size){

new_table = true;

cout<< "REHASH "<< endl;
//table1 is the second/temporary hash-table
//with the size of the new hash-table
table1 = new Node*[size];
//counter is reset
number_of_elements = 0;
int temp;
//Runner is used to traverse table1
Node * runner2;

//set the nodes to null
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    table1[i] = NULL;
}
//
for ( int i = 0; i < prev_size; i++ ) {
    Node * runner = table[i];
    while(runner != NULL){
        temp = runner->num;
        cout<<"temp: "<<runner->num<<"\n";
        //get new location
        int location = ((unsigned)temp) % size;
        cout<<"location: "<<location<<"\n";
        //store in new location
        runner2 = table1[location];
        runner2 = new Node(temp);
        cout<<runner2->num<<"\n";
        runner = runner->next;
        runner2 = runner2->next;
    }
}

//print out second/temporary hash-table
for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
    Node *runner  = table1[i];
    cout<< i << ". ";
    while(runner != NULL){
        cout<< runner->num << " ";
        runner = runner->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
//re-sizing original table
table = new Node*[size];
cout<< "New size " <<size<<endl;

for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    table[i] = NULL;
}
//copying the second/temp back to the first/original
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
   Node * runner = table1[i];
    while(runner != NULL){
        temp = runner->num;
        Node * runner2 = table[i];
        runner2 = new Node(temp);
        cout<<runner2->num<<"\n";
        runner = runner->next;
        runner2 = runner2->next;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Gave a quick look. One of the errors is:

runner2 = table1[location]; // runner2 becomes NULL
runner2 = new Node(temp);
// runner2 now contains pointer to a Node, but you table1[location] is still NULL.

Also you link list logic is wrong. Your nodes are not getting connected.
You should do something like:
runner->next = new Node(temp);

Essentially you need to work on you whole while(runner != NULL) logic.